# Alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names in function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function FindOffers
    ( przebieg_max IN number )
    RETURN offer_type_table
AS
    l_offers offer_type_table := offer_type_table();

BEGIN
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT * FROM szczegoly_oferty sz, oferty ofe
        WHERE  sz.przebieg <= przebieg_max AND sz.oferta_id = ofe.idk
    )
    LOOP
        l_offers.EXTEND;
        l_offers(l_offers.COUNT) := (offer_type('Auto',i.rok_produkcji,i.cena_aktualna,i.przebieg));
    END LOOP;

    RETURN l_offers;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

During the compilation it shows me the following error:

```
Alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names.
```

I used the aliases for tables in select query. Where can be the problem?

Comment: By the way, that exception handler does nothing useful and in fact will just obscure the line number and error message. Removing the whole exception section would improve error handling significantly.

Comment: _I used the aliases for tables in select query. Where can be the problem?_ The SELECT list is the list of columns between `select` and `from`. It's telling you to use some aliases there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems

> both tables `szczegoly_oferty` and `oferty` have at least one common
>   column.

To avoid ambiguity you have to use aliases for expressing column names individually with aliases `sz` and `ofe` like `SELECT sz.col1, ofe.col1, ofe.col2`  in the `SELECT list`.

Comment: Side note: The OP is using archaic pre ANSI-92 join syntax, and should replace with modern syntax.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure you're right, i've also realized that point.

Answer (score 0):

Only select the columns that you need.  *And* learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
FOR i IN (
    SELECT ?.rok_produkcji, ?.cena_aktualna, sz.przebieg
    FROM szczegoly_oferty sz JOIN
         oferty ofe
         ON sz.przebieg <= przebieg_max AND sz.oferta_id = ofe.idk
)
. . .
```

The `?` is for your to fill in the table aliases.